# How do i fix this error router in bootstrap.php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phpmyadmin, router

Hey there Good day im getting a error in bootstrap.php when I download my website from the server im getting this error below when I try to view it from Wampserver

( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'router' not found in C:\wamp\www\voasaconference\bootstrap.php on line 42
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0006  667272  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0009  687312  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\voasaconference\bootstrap.php' ) ..\index.php:8

Does anyone have an idea of to fix this error I would so much appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have CakePHP installed on the other webserver? I believe the router class is part of this and as you dont have it installed locally you get this error.

Comment: In the index.php heres the code

<?php/*
This file is where all starts from.
All requests are handled by this file.
Turn the sanity check on to see whether all is in place.
*/
require_once('./bootstrap.php');

Comment: bootstrap.php error im getting: $router=new router($uri);

Comment: Not sure what to do not familiar with cakePHP though any steps how to fix this error or if this got to do with cake PHP please direct me how to setup locally - many thanks

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cakephp+wamp+install